# Reading separated data from file to different data types in C language

Tags: c

I have trouble when I read these data into (int  string  float) in C language,
the compiler read the data after the first comma until the end of the line into string **(char[])**
and do not store any data in a float variable. Hope it understood.
thanks

> Blockquote
> 00979,Jack,133.2
> 11411,Tony,615.3
> 24451,Jasmen,655.9
> 77321,Ahmad,821
> 09022,Diana,179.3
> 19091,Tayma,776.6

**my code**

```
int flag =1,seat ;
char str[10];
float avg ;
while (flag !=EOF ){
    flag=fscanf(in,"%d , %s , %f",&seat,str,&avg);
    if(flag==EOF){
        break ;
    }
    printf("%d    %s    %f\n",seat,str,avg);
}
```

Comment: Better use `fgets` to get a line then `strtok` to find commas. And if you generate the data file, use tab (0x09) instead of comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%[^,]` specifier instead of `%s` specifier to read string until next comma.